# WSO2 REST proxy answer back with SOAP instead of REST

Tags: rest, soap, wso2, esb

Recently I had a problem with wso2 esb that I cannot resolve (maybe a bug). I will try to explain it as clear as possible.

I use the wso2 ESB with a rest proxy in order to communicate from a frontend application to a backend Rest service.

I defined a rest proxy with an endpoint like this and it worked fine:

```
<endpoint>
         <address uri="http://127.0.0.1:8099/DummyRestServiceWSO2"/>
</endpoint>
```

But our goal is to integrate WSO2 esb in a container inside an openshift environment. In openshift the ip are set dynamically but accessible through system environment variable. So I tried to solve my endpoint dynamically byusing the header tag:

```
<endpoint>
         <default/>
</endpoint>
<inSequence>
<script language="js">mc.setProperty("url",java.lang.System.getenv("HOST_IP"));</script>
<property name="service_url" expression="fn:concat(get-property(url),'/DummyRestServiceWSO2')"/>
<header name="To" expression="get-property('service_ep')"/>
<send/>
</inSequence>
```

Where HOST_IP is defined as: http://127.0.0.1:8099

Since I made this change my call to the backend rest service is still working fine but the response to the caller (frontend) is now formatted as soap (I tried to draw the problem, [see attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxeeU.png)).

Thanks a lot for your help and I wish a wonderfull day to whoever read this post :)

Answer (score 0):

If by "REST" you mean "JSON" format, just define this property before sending back the reponse to the client :

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
```

Use `application/xml` for plain xml (no SOAP envelope / body)

You also can use a default endpoint in send mediator and define the format :

```
<send>
  <endpoint>
    <default format="rest">
      <timeout>
        <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
      </timeout>
    </default>
  </endpoint>
</send>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Actually it didn't helped but I could find how to solve the problem:    
 the tag <send/> after the tag header need to be removed then it works